# How to install GNOME desktop from DVD on CentOS 6 using the command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, installation, gnome

I have installed CentOS 6 in Virtualbox. Although I have chosen to install General Purpose GNOME Desktop, the GNOME desktop does not start. All I get is a black and white text prompt. I would like to know how I can install GNOME Desktop from the CentOS DVD.

1. How do I mount the DVD image?
2. How do I install GNOME desktop from command line?
3. If I already have the GNOME Desktop installed, why doesn't it start? How can I check from command line that I have GNOME installled?

This virtual machine does not have internet connection, that's why I want to install the GNOME Desktop from DVD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have installed CentOS in VirtualBox, and as I understand, while installing you haven't choose X window system, so you are getting black screen with white cursor blinking.

Now what you can do is, install X Window System. If you have internet access in VirtualBox then you can try

```
yum groupinstall "X Window System"
```

This will use your internet connection to download the packages and install on system.

If you don't have internet access in VirtualBox then I will suggest you to mount the CD ROM in a virtual machine and install using that.

First of all you need to create a mount point and mount the Installation Media

```
mkdir -p /media/cdr
mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdr
```

Now you have to create a local repository in `/etc/yum.repo.d/`

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
vi local.repo
```

In this file write

```
[installtion Media]
Name="Centos Local Installation"
baseurl="file:///media/cdr"
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

Now you can install the X Window system using

```
yum groupinstall "X Window System"
```

Let me know if you still have any problem.

Comment: I applied this solution, but yum didn't like my local.repo, so I rewrote it, so the repo name had no spaces, and the base url had no "".

Comment: there are somes typos the line mkdir /medir/cdr should be mkdir /media/cdr and cd /etc/yum.repo.d/ should be cd /etc/yum.repos.d/

Comment: I had to set priority to ensure it used my local repo; see http://serverfault.com/questions/399207/how-to-only-allow-a-package-to-be-downloaded-from-a-specific-repository-using-yu